# UISwipeGestureRecognizer making app crash changing screens?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a simple 3 page app, I can go from page 1 to page 2 swiping left.

However, when I am on page 2, I need to add the ability to go to either page 1 swiping right, or page 3 swiping left, but it just keeps crashing.

I suspect it may be a memory release issue, but I wonder if you could be so kind as to check the code below for any glaring errors?

Many thanks,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [swipeLeftRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRight];
    [UISwipeGestureRecognizer release];

}

- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        Page3ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3ViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];
          [Page2ViewController release];
    }else{

        Page3ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];
        [Page2ViewController release];
    }

        }


- (IBAction)swipeRightDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

        [Page2ViewController release];

    }else{

        ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

        ViewController *VC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];

        [Page2ViewController release];

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending releases to what appear to be classes? It's also a good idea to not declare your iVars with the name of classes (ESPECIALLY UIKIT CLASSES!!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I found an older post by a person called rptwsthi, I used some of that to fix it;

Changed the viewDidLoad {

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
    [rightRecognizer release];

    //........towards left Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
    [leftRecognizer release];
```

And using this to switch the pages;

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Do moving

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

        [Page2ViewController release];

    }else{

        ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

        ViewController *VC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];

        [Page2ViewController release];

    }
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    // do moving

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        Page3ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3ViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];


    }else{

        Page3ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Not sure how neat it is in a true coders view, but it works, sometimes you just gotta go with what works right! :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You need to implement a method called `handleGesture:` since that's the action you're passing in to the gesture recognizer.

Comment: Hi Jeff, could you be a bit more specific at all (my mind is frazzled at the moment with code so please do excuse me!) Kind regards

Comment: I added that the swipeLeft part to test, but it still froze;

- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        Page3ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3ViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
        
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:[self.view.gestureRecognizers lastObject]];

        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:NO];

Comment: Ok. Then we'll need more info on the crash, especially what type of crash and what shows up in the debug console.

Comment: -[Page2ViewController handleGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c572ac0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Page2ViewController handleGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c572ac0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3997e2a3 0x36da597f 0x39981e07 0x39980531 0x398d7f68 0x3a73dd31 0x3a7053dd 0x3a8f2479 0x3a629837 0x3a62829b 0x3a6331ef 0x3a632dbb 0x3a620809 0x3a620123 0x393585a3 0x393581d3 0x39953173 0x39953117 0x39951f99 0x398c4ebd 0x398c4d49 0x393572eb 0x3a674301 0xb7925 0xb7888)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called